# Storing an XML file locally in Firefox

Tags: javascript, xml, file-io, firefox-addon

I am making a XUL extension for Firefox and I would like store an XML file locally in Firefox so that when I write to the file the data is stored permanently into the XML file even after I close the browser. Is there any way I can do this using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

See Serializing DOM trees to files on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Other options are :

a) You could try storing and reading it as a preference. At least if your XML is string-based and is rather small you can try something like below.

Use the PreferenceManager

```
var thePrefManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
```

To read the XML :

```
var myXML = thePrefManager.getCharPref("extensions.extensionName.prefName");
```

To store the XML :

```
thePrefManager.setCharPref("extensions.extensionName.prefName",myXML);
```

More info about writing prefs see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Preferences.

b) If you're trying to write/read from a file in your extension take a look at
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I//O)

Answer (score 0):

Greasemonkey does this exactly, it is MIT/X11:

- [Creating the xml and saving it as a file to disk](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/blob/0bace94e40dce18a26caae18cbd558b0c1e2577b/content/config.js#L92-128)
- [Reading the file on load](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/blob/0bace94e40dce18a26caae18cbd558b0c1e2577b/content/config.js#L67-90)

Use [NetUtils.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/NetUtil.jsm) for the file reading/writing though, it is easier.